# Rabbitmq connections management in Pyramid web app?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pyramid

How can I manage my rabbit-mq connection in Pyramid app?

I would like to re-use a connection to the queue throughout the web application's lifetime. Currently I am opening/closing connection to the queue for every publish call.

But I can't find any "global" services definition in Pyramid. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Pyramid does not need a "global services definition" because you can trivially do that in plain Python:

db.py:

```
connection = None

def connect(url):
    global connection
    connection = FooBarBaz(url)
```

your startup file (`__init__.py`)

```
from db import connect
if __name__ == '__main__':
    connect(DB_CONNSTRING)
```

elsewhere:

```
from db import connection
...
connection.do_stuff(foo, bar, baz)
```

Having a global (any global) is going to cause problems if you ever run your app in a multi-threaded environment, but is perfectly fine if you run multiple *processes*, so it's not a huge restriction. If you need to work with threads the recipe can be extended to use [thread-local variables](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.local). Here's another example which also connects lazily, when the connection is needed the first time.

db.py:

```
import threading

connections = threading.local()

def get_connection():
    if not hasattr(connections, 'this_thread_connection'):
        connections.this_thread_connection = FooBarBaz(DB_STRING)
    return connections.this_thread_connection
```

elsewhere:

```
from db import get_connection

get_connection().do_stuff(foo, bar, baz)
```

Another common problem with long-living connections is that the application won't auto-recover if, say, you restart RabbitMQ while your application is running. You'll need to somehow detect dead connections and reconnect.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can attach objects to the request with `add_request_method`.

Here's a little example app using that method to make one and only one connection to a socket on startup, then make the connection available to each request:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.response import Response

def index(request):
    return Response('I have a persistent connection: {} with id {}'.format(
        repr(request.conn).replace("<", "&lt;"),
        id(request.conn),
    ))

def add_connection():
    import socket
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect(("google.com", 80))
    print("I should run only once")
    def inner(request):
        return s
    return inner

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = Configurator()
    config.add_route('index', '/')
    config.add_view(index, route_name='index')
    config.add_request_method(add_connection(), 'conn', reify=True)
    app = config.make_wsgi_app()
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 8080, app)
    server.serve_forever()
```

You'll need to be careful about threading / forking in this case though (each thread / process will need its own connection). Also, note that I am not very familiar with pyramid, there may be a better way to do this.